# Can a server block requests from a website of mine?

Tags: php, httprequest, block

There's a website hosted on a server (A) that makes an HttpRequest via php to another website hosted on another server (B).

Every time a user click a button on the homepage of the website hosted on A, A makes a request to get an html page of B.

Can B block these requests from A?

Comment: Yes it can block them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes its possible.
Long answer: it is not practical. Although you can block a server's IP address, but if the server's owner really wants to do it, he/she can just get a free proxy and then send the request, you will never be able to tell if the request is sent from Server A or a valid user.

Comment: a curiosity, if server A sends requests under proxy then what can server B do as well as blocking proxy traffic?

Comment: @MananaBumBum you can never tell if the request is sent through a proxy or no. So server B will never know

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is yes.

There are multiple ways of doing this ranging from blocking your specific IP address to blocking request with specific headers (or even the missing headers).

A common method is not allowing hotlinking, which usually checks whether a referer header exists and if it matches their own site.

Comment: if its a Http Request sent from server A, referrer can be easily faked. about the blocking IP part, you will have to know which server you would want to block

Comment: @Steve do you mean that if server A makes HTTP requests, with faked referrer, via a proxy, server B can't block it?

Comment: @MananaBumBum I mean if server B is only checking the referrer field then yes, it can be easily faked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are many ways to do so, both through PHP and your firewall.

For example, you can put at the top of your PHP file on B

```
if( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "whatever-ip-here" ) die();
```

Another example uses Linux/iptables. It is a bit more involved to set up and will block everything originating from A (connections will be refused):

```
iptables -A INPUT -s putipaddresshere -j DROP
```